# Are there Ethernet Over Power WiFi Access Point devices?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, powerline-networking

I am looking for the following device, as part of my network configuration:

An Ethernet over Power device, that once plugged into the electrical socket (which already carries data) will function as an WiFi Access Point. I am not looking for an WiFi Extender device, as this WiFi AP is supposed to be the single WiFi point and not an extension of another WiFi router.

Current setup which I can use to do the same is:

Connect two Ethernet over Power devices. One connects to the router and the other connects to a WiFi Access Point.

With the 2nd setup, I need 2 Ethernet over Power devices plus an additional Access Point device. The device I am searching for combines both EoP and WiFi AP into a single device.

Does such a device exist?

If yes, I'd appreciate any keywords I should look for when searching for it and

If not, I would appreciate explanations as to why it doesn't exist, as it looks like a good idea.

RaamEE

Comment: Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs. 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like such a device does exist:

[http://www.amazon.com/NETGEAR-XWNB5201-Powerline-500Mbps-Access/dp/B009WG6K66](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009WG6K66)

Comment: I personally use TP-Link devices for this. Have them over 50 meters apart in some cases but perfect no-loss signal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they exist. If you google for `EoP Access Point` you'll get plenty of possibilities. This site is not about hardware recommendations because they get outdated rather quick.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, no. You will have to work with 2 separate devices. 1 EoP device and 1 AP connected to the EoP device.

EDIT: I stand corrected, please see the other answers for examples (e.g. NETGEAR XWNB5201 Powerline 500Mbps to N300 Wi-Fi Access Point)

Comment: He's looking for EoP, not PoE.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, typo... will edit my previous post :)